# Ignore spaces when user enter password

Tags: javascript, regex

Using regex of JavaScript for password meter,but it count space as character,want ignore whitespaces.

```
function passwordChanged() {
var strength = document.getElementById('strength');
var strongRegex = new RegExp("^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*#).", "g");
var mediumRegex = new RegExp("^(((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9]))|((?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9]))|((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])))", "g");
var medium_sRegex = new RegExp("^(((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*#))|((?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*#))|((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*#)))", "g");
var goodRegex = new RegExp("^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])", "g");
var enoughRegex = new RegExp("(?=.*[0-9])|(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*[A-Z]).*", "g");
var notenoughRegex = new RegExp("(?=.{9,}).*", "g");
var pwd = document.getElementById("password");
if (pwd.value.length == 0) {
    strength.innerHTML = 'Type Password';
} else if (false == notenoughRegex.test(pwd.value)) {
    strength.innerHTML = 'Add More Characters';
} else if (strongRegex.test(pwd.value)) {
    strength.innerHTML = '<span >Excellent!</span>';
} else if (goodRegex.test(pwd.value)) {
    strength.innerHTML = '<span>Good!</span>';
} else if (medium_sRegex.test(pwd.value)) {
    strength.innerHTML = '<span>Medium1!</span>';
} else if (mediumRegex.test(pwd.value)) {
    strength.innerHTML = '<span>Medium!</span>';
} else {
    strength.innerHTML = '<span>Weak!</span>';
}
```

}

Comment: Why would you want to ignore spaces?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but there are existing solutions for password strength.

Comment: Spaces are perfectly legit as password characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `.` could also match a space.

Instead you can use `\S` to match a non whitespace character.

So in all the places where you use `.*` you can use `\S*` without introducing an extra lookahead and use `^\S+$` for the full match.

A few notes on the patterns used:

- When asserting the presence of a character, instead of using `(?=.*[A-Z])` you could use [contrast](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#contrast) using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `(?=[^\sA-Z]*[A-Z])` preventing unnecessary backtracking
- In this part `(?=.{9,}).*` you don't need a lookahead, you can just match using `\S{9,}`
- If you only want to assert the presence of certain characters, you don't have to match and use the assertions only asserting the full match

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add this part into your regex string to disable whitespaces in password. In this case, if there are spaces in the password, the password will not be verified:

```
(?=\S+$)
```

Also, you need to add anoser "if" branch to check when password is not valid

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment due to my low score.
A workaround could be replace the space with '' and then check it with regex exp.

As @andlrc suggested, replaceAll will do the job:

```
let pswToTest = pwd.value.replaceAll(' ','')
```

Comment: When the pattern is a string then `.replace` will only replace the first occurrence of the match, either use `.replaceAll` or use a regex with the global flag set, as the pattern: `.replace(/ /g`

Comment: @sahil Use `.replaceAll` after 
`var pwd = document.getElementById("password");`

Comment: I want to ignore whitespace at real time not after submission.@ llandino

Comment: @sahil then you just need to test `pswToTest` instead of `pwd`. After all the checks, if the password is strong, keep `pwd`